# DataGridView display row header cell

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm trying to display a simple DataGridView linked to a DataTable and I want, ultimately, my first column in the DataTable to be the row header cell for the DataGridView.  At this point I will settle for having any value in the row header cell.  I can display the DataGridView with all my rows and columns, and with column header cells, but no row header cell.  I check the value in the row.HeaderCell.Value, and the data I put there is there.  I check row.HeaderCell.Displayed and it is false, but this is read only, so I can't make it true.  How do I make the row header cell display?

Here's a simple sample of what I've tried to get this to work:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column-" + i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow theRow = table.NewRow();

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                theRow[j] = i + "-" + j;
            table.Rows.Add(theRow);

        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders;
        int rowNumber = 1;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
            row.HeaderCell.Value = "Row " + rowNumber;
            rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;
        }
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(
            DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you place this code in the constructor, it will not work. Move the code into the form's `Load` event and it should work fine. A common problem with Windows.Forms and C# is the use of improper initialization in the constructor. Many controls are not fully created until after the constructor finishes. (I forget why, but I believe it is because the handle is not created yet.) Many "work arounds" can be avoided, if you initialize in the `Load` event as recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 5):

Just call ToString() as given below

```
 row.HeaderCell.Value = ("Row " + rowNumber).ToString();
```

Comment: @Andro Selva: If this logic is linked to CTOR then I cannot see the HeaderCell value when the form is rendered. If I call this method in Form_Load(), this works. :)

Comment: Heh, after trying everything else, I tried this and it worked. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Try the DataGridView.RowHeadersVisible property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible.aspx

Comment: That turns the header cell on and off in it's entirety, my problem was that the value I put in the cell was not showing up in the display.  Figured it out below.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be handling the DataGridView.CellFormatting event.  Why setting the value elsewhere doesn't work is beyond me, but I'm sure there's a reason.  I added the following event handler and all is good:

```
    private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView gridView = sender as DataGridView;

        if (null != gridView)
        {

            gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
            Console.WriteLine("GridViewCell: " + gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe this is some kind of bug. In VB.NET, you can set `HeaderCell.Value` as needed. Yet, your have to resort to your work around in C#.

Comment: This is because the code is run from constructor. Move code to Load event or other event handler.

Comment: This is called for every column, so it is a little wasteful. You might want to change it so that it checks e.ColumnIndex == 0 before it sets the HeaderCell.Value.

Answer (score 1):

After assigning values to the datagridview, either by binding or manually, i did the following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvValues.Rows)
{
     row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index+1).ToString();
}
```

and it worked for me. I think there should be some even simpler workaround in Linq.

Answer (score 1):

I used Karl's answer, but changed the event handler to RowsAdded, assuming the row header name is not changing once the row is created.  The issue with CellFormatting is that it is called for every column, so it wastes some time setting the HeaderCell.Value over and over again.

```
    private void dataGridViewVersions_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView gridView = sender as DataGridView;
        MyData vr = gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as MyData ;
        if (vr != null)
        {
            gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = vr.RowName.ToString();
        }
    }
```